# How to draw a line on a web page using dojo

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I'm new to Dojo and javascript.  Trying to figure out some basics.  If I have a number of `<div>` objects, is there a way to draw and/or animate a line between them?

I see dojox/drawing/tools/Line which can be used to draw within a dojox.drawing.Drawing, but I don't have a drawing in which I want to add a line.  Instead, I just want to draw an arrow between two locations on the web page.  I suspect by dynamically creating and adding a `<div>`, turning it into an "line" using dojo, styling it, and positioning it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with Stylesheets?

Here's a fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kjjNY/

This is my first Div

```
<div id="first" style="width: 100%; height: 10px; border-bottom:2px; border-bottom-style:solid"></div>
<div>This is my second Div</div>
    <div id="second" style="width: 100%; height: 10px; border-bottom:2px; border-bottom-style:solid"></div>
<div>This is my third Div</div>
```

It's the simpliest way to define a border between two divs.

Regards, Miriam